# Change App Icon After Apple Approves iPhone App

Tags: iphone, icons, app-store

I submitted a new update to my app where application .plist points to a new icon. But in AppStore I still see the old icon after my app was launched. I suspect I did not click 'Save' when uploading new 512px icon during submission process or something like that happened. Anyway, when users load the app, the new icon is displayed which is great. But AppStore shows the old icon still. 
Now how do I change the icon (most likely it's the 512px one) without resubmitting the app?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide?](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) If you really do not want to go through the review process again, you could try to use the "Contact us" form in iTunes Connect, to get in touch with the review people at Apple. Maybe they let you change the App Store icon.